# Play Framework: How to configure compileable [LESS] assets outside of /app

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a play 2.0.2 (scala) project which uses bootstrap.  I've added bootstrap as a git submodule so that I can easily change its version without having to copy individual files around.

My project structure looks like:

```
project
  |_ bootstrap
  |    \_ img
  |    \_ js
  |    \_ less
  |         \_ bootstrap.less
  |         \_ responsive.less
  |_ app
       \_ assets
            \_ css
                \_ my.less
```

My Build.scala has:

```
def customLessEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder = (
    (base / "app" / "assets" / "css" * "*.less") +++
    (base / "bootstrap" / "less" / "bootstrap.less") +++
    (base / "bootstrap" / "less" / "responsive.less")
)

def externalAssets(base: File): PathFinder = (base / "bootstrap")
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "bootstrap",
  playExternalAssets <+= baseDirectory.apply(file => (file, externalAssets(_), "bootstrap")),
  lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(customLessEntryPoints)
  // other settings
)
```

When I access the web application after doing "~ run", (or if I run play-copy-assets) I get:

```
[error] {file:/<path_to_project>/}<project>/*:play-copy-assets: No mapping for <path_to_project>\bootstrap\less\bootstrap.less
[error] application -

! Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [RuntimeException: No mapping for <path_to_project>\bootstrap\less\bootstrap.less]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:233) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:226) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4.apply(PlayReloader.scala:226) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4.apply(PlayReloader.scala:224) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:183) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
java.lang.RuntimeException: No mapping for <path_to_project>\bootstrap\less\bootstrap.less
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:66) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at sbt.Mapper$$anonfun$fail$1.apply(PathMapper.scala:26) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.Mapper$$anonfun$fail$1.apply(PathMapper.scala:26) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.Alternatives$$anon$1$$anonfun$$bar$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PathMapper.scala:61) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.Alternatives$$anon$1$$anonfun$$bar$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PathMapper.scala:61) ~[na:na]
```

I'd like the img and js subfolders of bootstrap to be served as assets (alongside or in a different path to the static ones in public) and the bootstrap|responsive.less files compiled into css and served as well.

The custom entry points work fine.  That is, if I change them so they're all under /app and move the less files from bootstrap in there, they work.  If I move the image and js files under public, that works too.  But what I'm trying to achieve is the clean separation.

I'm pretty sure I haven't correctly understood how to use playAssetsDirectories and playExternalAssets, I've tried many variations for these settings.  I'm not sure if what I'm trying is possible or how the settings should relate - e.g. does a lessEntryPoint have to be in an asset directory, and are externalAssets considered asset directories?  Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying for clean separation, you may be better off disabling the internal compiler, and using an external tool like Crunch.

If you're not doing that, you may want to restrict Play to use a SINGLE file (my.less) and then include all the others from within there.  You cannot compile LESS files using the internal compiler from the public directory -- they are static assets only.  If you want Play to have access to them, they should go under app/stylesheets.

Also be aware that LESS 1.3 has some significant problems when trying to compile files that are in sub directories -- this has bitten multiple people on the play-framework mailing list, and Bootstrap in particular is known to blow up with errors.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer.  I'll try the approach of using import in LESS and update with the results.

Comment: I tried this out and I can get it to work as long as every less file (all the way down the import tree) is imported directly into the one Play2 knows about.  Essentially my.less file became an edited bootstrap.less.

Answer (score 1):

I have applied Bootstrap LESS into my projects as the following:

Have Bootstrap "import" files in asset directory. Play will compile them.

```
app\assets\bootstrap.less
app\assets\responsive.less
```

Have the other ".less" files in e.g. `app\less`

Edit the bootstrap.less file that the path refers to `app\less` directory

```
@import "../less/reset.less";
```

Physically the compliled CSS goes to

```
\target\scala-2.9.1\resource_managed\main\public
```

but you can still refer to them as they would be in the public

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap.css")">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can definitely get bootstrap compiling properly when the .less files are under /app, but my question is specifically about how to keep bootstrap cleanly separated, i.e. outside of /app.

Comment: my dummy clarification, whatabout if you have only the importing bootstap.less in app/assets and edit the paths in it "@import "..what/ever/path/outside/app/reset.less". Is there some particural reason why you want bootstrap outside of 'app'?

Comment: The reason I want bootstrap outside is so that I can manage it as a git submodule making it trivial to update to a new version.  All I have to do when there's a new version of bootstrap is checkout the tag in the submodule and fix any incompatibilities, not copy files into different parts of the play app.  I'll try the import, which I think will work, will then need to figure out how to add bootstrap/img and bootstrap/js to the assets controller.